# How to hide a chart in a section

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a chart element in a section on my form, I need to hide the chart according to some rules, I know the way to hide a tab or a section but If I want to show/hide chart element according to it's unique name what is the xrm\Js syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see something similar to this on a form:

[image: chart on form]

It's nothing more than a subgrid set as a chart:

[image: subgrid as chart properties]

If I get your situation you just need to implement the logics and execute "form context or xrm.page or whatever you use + `.getControl("Subgrid_unique_name").setVisible(false/or/true);`"

Where false hide and true shows

Comment: ty @RiveN 4 the edit ill improve the way i answer